# how can I reach to "my computer" on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I use Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.
I want to reach to "my computer" on Explorer that shows C drive, and other exist drives.
Windows 7 can shows that, but I can't see it in WinServ2012.

I find "PC" menu(*1) on Explorer so I Entered there but I only can see those folders: download, desktop, document, picture, video, music and there is no physical drives.

How can I reach to the menu that like "my computer" on Win7?
by the way that PC has only C drive, is that causes this?

*1: I use Japanese OS, May be other Language shows another folder/menu name.

Answer (score -1):

I found out solution for this problem.
The problem was my Explorer doesn't show "devices and drives" group on "PC" folder.
There are only "Folders" group that showing download, desktop, etc.
And the solution for that problem is troubleshooting of "hardware and devices" I know, but there is no menu like that(my troubleshooting shows only 6 menus, and there is no "hardware and devices" troubleshooting).
After that, I found that PC folder showing "devices and drives" group and I don't realize it.
Finally, I don't know what act solved this problem, but the problem was solved, so I close this topic.
If anyone know the solution, please write that here.